# change resolution on server boot screen resolution

Tags: server, grub2, screen, display-resolution, ubuntu-minimal

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 minimal and Kodi 16 (Jarvis) onto 64-bit AMD mobo with a Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series video card using [these instructions](http://www.richud.com/wiki/Ubuntu_Minimal_KODI_Install)

I setup kodi to autostart using a nopassword user `kodi` using [these instructions](http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Autostart_Kodi_for_Linux#Use_autologin_feature_of_lightdm). Everything went well and Kodi runs beautifully displaying on my 50" Panasonic Viera plasma, which is connected to the Radeon card via HDMI.

My problem is the boot/terminal screen resolution, which is way overscanned, to the extent that the screen is extended about 10 columns too far left of the visible screen. IOW, in a terminal window, I cannot see the `$` prompt or any text to the left of roughly 12-14 characters.

I can SSH into the server easily and I've tried to use `xrandr` (as root and with `sudo`), but I can only get `Can't open display`. When I try to change to the user `kodi` to run `xrandr`, I'm asked for a password and the system will not accept the blank password (user kodi has no password).

I'm sure I need to adjust the default screen resolution to something along the lines of 1280x720, but I cannot do so. I've read some solutions that suggest a grub config edit, but I'm not sure this is how I need to go.

I've also looked at [the X instructions here](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution) but I have no `xorg.conf` file and I cannot get `xrandr` to show me anything except `Can't open display`. I can do anything I need to do via SSH, but I'd like to be able to see a terminal screen on the TV display when necessary.

Thanks for any tips!